# Refresh permissions from in-memory cache with ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: caching, asp.net-boilerplate, cache-invalidation

When I explicitly set a permission for a user in the database by running a SQL update script, the particular permission with the latest grant is not reflecting in the system. However when I recycle the IIS process or rebuild the solution, it only then seems to update.

It looks like the framework is using some kind of in-memory store for checking permissions.

Is there a "force refresh" function in ABP that I can call to refresh the in-memory store with the latest permissions from the database?

The weird thing is that when setting the permission via the front-end, the permission does work as expected without IIS recycling, so it definitely calls into some kind of function to update its cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `ICacheManager` and clear the cache:

```cs
public void ForceRefresh()
{
    _cacheManager.GetUserPermissionCache().Clear();
 // _cacheManager.GetRolePermissionCache().Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Setting Manager caches settings on the server-side, so you should not directly change a setting value using a repository or database update query.

If your 3rd party application wants to change a setting, it should do it via WebAPI methods. So you need to create an Application Service and add a method something like `ChangeSettingValue({settingName, settingValue})`.

In this app service inject `ISettingManager`, and use `ChangeSettingForApplicationAsync`, `ChangeSettingForTenantAsync` or `ChangeSettingForUserAsync` methods (and sync versions) to change settings for the application, for a tenant and for a user respectively.

See the related docs > https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Setting-Management

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I need a way to reset permissions for running automated UI tests against it.

Comment: in any way, you need to trigger cacheManager.clear() manually